# Gas Cooled Fast Reactor Coolants

Tags: energy

I know that helium and CO2 are used as fast reactor coolants, but how about other inert gasses with low neutron absorption, like argon, why do I see no papers on that?

Oh and bonus question. Why is there no solid fuel which uses a metal foam to conduct heat from the fuel pin to the caldding?

Comment: I remember that one or more Venus landers filled their capsules with xenon as an insulator, because its heat capacity is about 1/100th that of, e.g., hydrogen.

Answer (score 0):

Argon is not used because it is too easily activated by neutrons, forming Ar-41, which has half-life of 1.8 hours.
https://books.google.com/books?id=YvLum7UFjK8C&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=argon+reactor+coolant&source=bl&ots=iIuB3vgjbY&sig=AEp-YJ5ZTLK2ytBHMAowzt1Jusg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwADgKahUKEwjbz5PLlOjGAhWEnoAKHRdYAG8#v=onepage&q=argon%20reactor%20coolant&f=false

As for the bonus, I'd guess that, by nature, metal foam is always less thermally conductive than solid metal. This is not exactly a useful property under the circumstances.